# Box vagrant does not change after box update

Tags: vagrant

I have vagrant box, and I make a change to upgrade box.

I ran "vagrant package --output new.box" to save the box and I upload to the server so my friend can download it.
He downloaded it but when he ran "vagrant box update", the box did not change.
Do I have to destroy the vagrant box first if I want to apply the change? Thank you

Comment: poor structure question

Comment: just leave it alone if you don't want to help

Comment: this is for your goodness. you must see how to ask good questions. or-else you'll be blocked (not by me)

Answer (score 2):

From the `vagrant box update` command's [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#box-update).

> Note that updating the box will not update an already-running Vagrant machine. To reflect the changes in the box, you will have to destroy and bring back up the Vagrant machine.

This means that you will need to `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` to get the new version to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove everything entirely, after this you reinstall it and it should update.

Answer (score 0):

By default [vagrant box version](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/versioning.html) will work specially from boxes that are uploaded on Altas (which is hashicorp product) as atlas creates a default metadata file when you push boxes there.

You can certainly create the [box metadata](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html) file yourself

> It is a JSON document, structured in the following way:
>
> ```
> {   "name": "hashicorp/precise64",   "description": "This box contains Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit.",   "versions": [
>     {
>       "version": "0.1.0",
>       "providers": [
>         {
>           "name": "virtualbox",
>           "url": "http://somewhere.com/precise64_010_virtualbox.box",
>           "checksum_type": "sha1",
>           "checksum": "foo"
>         }
>       ]
>     }   ] }
> ```
>
> As you can see, the JSON document can describe multiple versions of a
>   box, multiple providers, and can add/remove providers in different
>   versions.

If you did not create this metadata file before, your friend will need to create it in their existing box so vagrant can make the match when you will run the `update` command.